# python mkdir/makesdir folder name with special symbol

Tags: python, file, directory, mkdir

Getting OSError:

> [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'Example > Folder' Error

with

```
os.mkdir('Example > Folder')
```

How can I keep special symbols like ">" in my directory name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What characters are forbidden in Windows and Linux directory names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names)

Answer (score 1):

If your operating system / file system does not support those symbols in a directory name, then you cannot keep those special symbols.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `>` character in a file/folder name in Windows. There's nothing you can do from Python's side if the underlying OS won't allow it.